# Can't install Microsoft.Graph package

Tags: xamarin, office365, visual-studio-2017, microsoft-graph-api

I'm getting this error when trying to install `Microsoft.Graph` in a brand new Xamarin.forms (PCL) project with a Prism-Unity template:

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.Graph 1.5.0'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does
>   not contain any assembly references or content files that are
>   compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the
>   package author.

I've tried other versions as well at targeting other profiles but nothing worked. Any ideas on how to install it with Xamarin.forms?

*Update:*
I can install it in a Shared Project environment which is not satisfying, especially since Office365 Xamarin showcase solution is a PCL so it should work. That solution by the way is set to target "portable, version=7.0" (not really sure why or how to do that...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your project needs to be updated. There is an article that describes the process of changing your Xamarin projects to target .NET Platform Standard: [.NET Standard Library with Xamarin Forms](https://xamarinhelp.com/dot-net-standard-pcl-xamarin-forms).

Comment: You weren't too far. The issue actually was the targeting platform. Which is strange for a Microsoft product to only work once I removed .Net core and windows 10 support.... Anyway for the record I used profile 46 (portable46-net451+win81)

Comment: I'm glad to hear it is working. There are enough subtle differences between Mono, .NET Framework and .NET Core to cause headaches. Thankfully we're converging on a single model but things are still in that "awkward transition" period. :)